# Sticky bar implementation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a working "sticky bar" implementation using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/mdyv740o/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    .top-container {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .header {
    }

    .content {
      padding: 16px;
    }

    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky .sticky-body {
      background: #555;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 90px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top-container">
  <h1>My Sticky Bar Demo</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect....</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button">Button 5</button>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo,
    maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam
    omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no
    molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    var $header = $("#myHeader");
    $header.hide();

    //wrap in div
    var $body = $header.wrapInner("<div></div>").children().addClass("sticky-body");

    var myFunction = function() {
      var sticky = $header[0].offsetTop;
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        $header.addClass("sticky").show();
      } else {
        $header.removeClass("sticky").hide();
      }
    };

    $(window).on("scroll", myFunction);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, when the page is loaded, the toolbar is not shown yet. Eventually user scrolls down a bit, then the toolbar will be visible, at almost top of the screen. The toolbar is kept visible until the user scrolls up, reaching near top of the screen. And so one.

Now my supervisor asked me to rewrite that in React. And no jQuery at all. I've done all the UI part. What I still cannot figure out is how to render the sticky bar visible/invisible based on scrolling. How to do this?

[This is what I have so far](https://gist.github.com/anta40/5219bf92e7999c966fcdc137918ed17f).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the class name `header` to a `state` property .Toggling it to `header sticky` using `setState()` as the `window.pageYOffset` is above the par range

Open this link I've made the above said change. [Link](https://gist.github.com/mahendrabharath/c6e59d3c756b785a8d2f3873a987b0a8)